# How to get all involved letter in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

In mysql , I am able to get rid of all repeat row by using `DISTINCT`.

But I am trying to do this with a string in PHP.

Let say I have a String like `asbbbdasddbb`.

How do I remove all repeating letter and get result like `asbd`?

This is my current code

```
preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", "asbbbdasddbb");
```

but it is returning string `asbdasdb`.

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: updated question , thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(.)(?=.*\1)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lS1nO8/3

```
$re = "/(.)(?=.*\\1)/m"; 
$str = "asbbbdasddbb"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: I've found similar reg too , but I have test it with string "aaab" and it is still returning the same string "aaab" , do you mind to elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am sorry , it was my mistake , I have $1 as second parameter

Answer (score 4):

This will do:

```
echo join('', array_unique(str_split('asbbbdasddbb')));
```

Comment: And it preserves the order of appearance.